# How can `from src.square import Square` be turned into `from square import Square`?

Tags: python

In the following sample code:

[sample-python-library](https://github.com/panlex2010/sample-python-library)

the file containing unit tests is unable to find the class definition in the src directory.

Executing the unittest command from the test/ and root directories cause different errors:

```
cd test/
python -m unittest test_square
...
from src.square import Square
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'


cd ..
python -m unittest test/test_square.py
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test.test_square'
```

With such a basic consideration, I am unable to locate the best practices. Even the official documentation's [test-discovery](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery) section is of no assistance. Other official Python documentation describes how the runtime path is constructed, but do not appear to provide a clear mechanism for code developers to embed a directory layout structure which is recognized by the runtime.

Placing a path_file.pth file containing the local directories also did not work. Not only did this not fix the problem, it appeared to have no effect on the path as report by sys.path, which appears to contradict the documented behavior of Python when encountering *.pth files.

Obviously, a system script could be written which manipulates the PYTHONPATH variable. Also sys could be used in the code somewhere. But neither of these solutions is at all elegant.

What is the solution? How does everyone else write unit tests and instruct Python to locate the source files from inside the test subdirectory?

Comment: Make your package installable using a `src` layout, then install it as editable in your venv: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/src-layout-vs-flat-layout/

Comment: Ahhhh....... AKX you have found what I was unable to locate in the documentation. Spot on!

Answer (score 1):

src folder shouldn't be a package.

If you want to follow the src layout, remove the `src/__init__.py`, make a `square` folder inside src, then create an `src/square/__init__.py` file to make it a package, and move `square.py` to the newly created folder. With that, you'll be able to do `from square.square import Square`.

If you want to do `from square import Square`, do a `from square.square import Square` inside `src/square/__init__.py`.

Comment: Awesome Joao thank you for your response. I think you are correct about adding the import statement to the __init__.py. However the problem I've had is any arrangement with src/ directory fails when I try to import. Specifically I have tried removing the __init__.py, adding a square module with __init__.py, etc. I have tried many arrangements but with no luck.